# Unable to read Contacts email address from site page ( in manage package)

Tags: managed-package, force.com-sites, contact

I want to query contacts email address when logged in from a site, but I am unable to read the value of the email field of contact object. Is there any limitation for site user which will not allow reading email field value of contact record?
Please note: code that we are executing is part of a managed package.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is part of a managed package, you are limited in updating the code in the package. Having said that, you might be able to get the information indirectly. Here are some options:

1. Some managed packages give you the ability to customize their package for common use cases. Contact the vendor for assistance
2. If the customer takes an action on the page that results in a DML, then you can write a trigger on that object to do what you need (You can write triggers on objects that are part of a managed package).

Hope this helps, and welcome to the community!